# How to get the UWP package associated with an UWP process?

Tags: uwp

[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) seems to have a magical way of determining which package a UWP process belongs to:[image]

[image]

Somehow, both process have identical names (`RuntimeBroker.exe`), starts from an identical path (`C:\Windows\System32`), and are passed identical, meaningless command arguments (`-Embedding`).

The other processes are passed some `ServerName` argument as a hint, but the `RuntimeBroker`s are not.

So my question is: **How can we know which package started the `RuntimeBroker`s, like what Process Explorer did?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic is right here, at home:
[image: Magic]

Simply use `tasklist /apps` and every UWP-related thing will be shown.

P.S. Confirmed only on Windows 10 20H2. I don't know for how long has this feature been available.

Answer (score 1):

> How can we know which package started the RuntimeBrokers, like what Process Explorer did?

I'm afraid you can't detect if the packaged app contains `RuntimeBrokers`, and currently, UWP Diagnostics API only could get limit process info such as [`CpuUsage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo?view=winrt-19041), and here is [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/AppModelSamples/tree/master/Samples/UWPTaskMonitor) that you could test with.

The Runtime Broker application is a Microsoft program included with Windows 8 (and newer versions) that handles permissions for all local Universal Windows Platform (UWP) applications.

The purpose of Runtime Broker is to monitor and manage all permissions granted to running UWP applications. If you’ve ever opened the Windows Store, or launched any UWP application from a built-in start menu “tile” or open FileOpenPicker chances are this application has used the Runtime Broker to verify its proper permissions and Capabilities.

And it is system leave, if you do want to check it when app running, we suggest you make desktop extension for uwp app, and load info with Win32 API.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do more research on this. I know what the Runtime Broker does, and I am deliberately trying to kill the Runtime Broker associated with a specific app.

Comment: It's not good practice to kill Runtime Broker, that will cause app arises  unexpected behavior.

Comment: Interesting... it does show that `RuntimeBroker` is a Packaged app. I will investigate more   after my exams... An upvote, and I will accept the answer if I make this stuff work!